# How to hide products without stock from layered navigation

Tags: php, magento

I have set all options in the Magento catalog configuration to hide out of stock products. This works fine, except for the layered navigation. I got a product attribute for the size of a product. So for example, I got 15 products with size 38 and 7 of them are out of stock. Still, in the layered navigation it says there are 15 products with size 38. Also when clicking the filter, all 15 products appear.

I found a lot of similar questions, only all are meant for Magento versions 1.3 and older (since it seems older Magento versions didn't had the option to hide out of stock products at all).

Could it be I missed a setting in the backend, on the attribute or stock configuration which causes this conflict?

Since I thought it was kind of a Magento bug, I also searched trough the core code of the layered navigation, but couldn't find a quick solution.

Anyone who can help me out?

Edit: Forgot to mention the products are configurable products. It looks like it only looks at the main product.

Comment: Have you reindexed the Product Attributes index after you changed the configuration settings?

Comment: Yes i did, and also caching is disabled for development. Also editted the post, think it has something to do with the configurable products.

Comment: [Hiding out of stock in layered navigation](http://colin.mollenhour.com/2009/09/28/yet-another-hiding-out-of-stock-products-update) might be worth a look.

Comment: Allready tried, that module is meant for older Magento versions, doesn't do anything on Magento 1.4+.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's little bit of topic, but have you considered using SCP module?
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

Comment: I know this extension and has a different purpose. This doesn't change the configurable products itself, only the pricing. Instead of taking the price of the main product it takes the price of the related product. A nice extension, but doesn't work in this case :)

Comment: I mentioned it because I had similar problem with wrong number in layered navigation. And in that project, I'm using SCP module. Unfortunately I don't remember, how I fixed it.
What version of Magento do you use? Newest 1.6.2.0?

Comment: I tried to reproduce issue on 1.6.2.0 with some configurable products, but it works correctly